# Regex - Is there a way to find across a substring string in any order?

Tags: regex, string, substring

So i'm currently having an issue in getting around Regex for the following situation:

Situation 1(It just states that there is only one country affected):
(...)@MT(...)

Situation 2(It shows multiple countries affected):
(...)@MT,GR,DE,FR(...)
With no defined order whatsoever so it could be like the one above or (...)"@GR,MT,FR,DE"(...), etc

what i reached for the Situation 1 would be quite simple but the rest i'm a bit clueless...

This i what i've already tried going towards to what i want

It gets Situation 1 and "half" of Situation 2 (only the second occurrence)

```
^.*NOTES="#P\d\s\@(?<affected_MT>(MT|\,MT|(?>\,[A-Z]{2})*\,MT)).*$
```

My target would be to get to find the instance "MT" in the string taking into account that it could happen in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
NOTES="#P\d+\s+@(?:[A-Z]{2},)*MT\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gcnm38/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=NOTES%3D%22%23P%5Cd%2B%5Cs%2B%40(%3F%3A%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%2C)*MT%5Cb).

It matches

- `NOTES=#P` - a `NOTES=#P` substring
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?:[A-Z]{2},)*` - zero or more sequences of 2 uppercase ASCII letters followed with a comma
- `MT\b` - a whole word `MT` (`\b` is a word boundary).

[image]